# MPAndroidChart is not animated when calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is there supposed to be animation when I have an updated set of data values, and then updating the chart with them values and calling `chart.notifyDataSetChanged` in [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)?

I would assume the effect would be similar to the bar growing in length or reducing in length accordingly, but it simply just snaps to the value.

Code:

```
                        if (m_chartHourlySales.getData() != null &&
                                m_chartHourlySales.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0)
                        {
                            set1 = (BarDataSet)m_chartHourlySales.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
                            set1.setValues(values.value);
                            m_chartHourlySales.getData().notifyDataChanged();
                            m_chartHourlySales.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } else {
                            set1 = new BarDataSet(values.value, getResources().getString(R.string.total_sales_figures_for_each_hour));
                            set1.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
                                @Override public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler)
                                {    
                                    return NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault()).format(value);
                                }
                            });
                            set1.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                            ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
                            dataSets.add(set1);

                            BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
                            data.setValueTextSize(10f);
                            data.setBarWidth(barWidth.value);

                            m_chartHourlySales.moveViewToX(0);
                            m_chartHourlySales.setData(data);

                            m_chartHourlySales.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(17*20);
                            m_chartHourlySales.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(17*6);

                            m_chartHourlySales.moveViewToX(0);
                        }
                        m_chartHourlySales.invalidate();
                        m_chartHourlySales.refreshDrawableState();
```

Comment: Please add some code what you have done.

Comment: Try to use `chart.invalidate();` & `chart.refreshDrawableState();` after `chart.notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: I've added the code for the chart. Also tried adding `chart.refreshDrawableState();` but it seems there's no difference though

Comment: Did you add animation to your chart? If not add `m_chartHourlySales.animateY(3000,Easing.EasingOption.EaseOutBack);`

Comment: Yes, you may need to add `chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I added that to my `if` and it worked. I had previously set it up once; didn't know it was on demand. However, since that function/if could be called repeatedly and hence the animation will replay possibly many times even when there are no changes in data. Is there support in the MPAndroidChart api to animate from existing values instead of from 0? It would be very glaring if on each animate call it starts from 0.